# pstricks is not work properly

Tags: pstricks

I am using pstricks package to draw a figure in pdflatex build setting, but in output pdf, the figure is missing. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\def\pdfshellescape{1}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
text here

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-4.34)(6.54,2.14)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.12,2.14)(0.0,-3.98)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.54,-3.5)(5.7,-4.34)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, shadow=true,shadowsize=0.10583334,shadowcolor=blue, 
dimen=outer](3.34,0.78)(1.3,-1.26)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, shadow=true,shadowsize=0.10583334,shadowcolor=blue, 
fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red, dimen=outer](2.46,-1.42)(1.46,-2.42)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you actually run it with shell-escape enabled? That is not something you can do from with in LaTeX (for obvious reasons as being able to run arbitrary commands is a security risk)

Comment: `\def\pdfshellescape{1}` will break all tests for whether shell escape is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
[...]
```

and then `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are a AUCTeX user, you don't need using package auto-pst-pdf.
Just set the variable TeX-PDF-from-Dvi to "Dvips" and TeX-PDF-mode to 1.
This can be done (for instance) with add-file-local-variable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
%\def\pdfshellescape{1}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
text here

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-4.34)(6.54,2.14)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.12,2.14)(0.0,-3.98)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.54,-3.5)(5.7,-4.34)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, shadow=true,shadowsize=0.10583334,shadowcolor=blue, 
dimen=outer](3.34,0.78)(1.3,-1.26)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, shadow=true,shadowsize=0.10583334,shadowcolor=blue, 
fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red, dimen=outer](2.46,-1.42)(1.46,-2.42)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-PDF-from-DVI: "Dvips"
% eval: (TeX-PDF-mode 1)
% End:
```